# How to check if the device has already passed a position with GoogleMaps?

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, geofencing, android-geofence

I'm using a `LocationListener` of GoogleMaps API to work with maps. In my application this draws a line of the route travelled by the user. I want to set an alert when the user is in a position they have already been to. But I don't know if there exists a service that does this for me or do I have a implement all. I don't understand the concept of geolocalization.

So, I wants alerts the user, when it is passing over the route traced.

```
private class FollowMeLocationSource implements LocationSource, LocationListener {

    private OnLocationChangedListener onLocationChangedListener;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;

    private final Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    private String bestAvailableProvider;

     /* Updates are restricted to one every 10 seconds, and only when
     * movement of more than 10 meters has been detected.*/
     private final long minTime = 2000;
     private final float minDistance = 5;

     private FollowMeLocationSource() {

         locationManager = (LocationManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
         getBestAvailableProvider();
         // Specify Location Provider criteria
         criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
         criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
         criteria.setAltitudeRequired(true);
         criteria.setBearingRequired(true);
         criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
         criteria.setCostAllowed(true);

         locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestAvailableProvider,minTime,minDistance,this);
     }

    private void getBestAvailableProvider() {
        /* The preferred way of specifying the location provider (e.g. GPS, NETWORK) to use
         * is to ask the Location Manager for the one that best satisfies our criteria.
         * By passing the 'true' boolean we ask for the best available (enabled) provider. */
        bestAvailableProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        Log.i(TAG,"bestAvailableProvider: " + bestAvailableProvider);
    }

    /* Activates this provider. This provider will notify the supplied listener
     * periodically, until you call deactivate().
     * This method is automatically invoked by enabling my-location layer. */
    @Override
    public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener listener) {
        Log.i(TAG,"activate");
        // We need to keep a reference to my-location layer's listener so we can push forward
        // location updates to it when we receive them from Location Manager.
        onLocationChangedListener = listener;

        // Request location updates from Location Manager
        if (bestAvailableProvider != null) {
            //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestAvailableProvider, minTime, minDistance, this);
            Log.i(TAG,"activate, bestProvider != null");
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestAvailableProvider,minTime,minDistance,this);
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG,"activate, bestProvider == null");
            // (Display a message/dialog) No Location Providers currently available.
        }
    }

    /* Deactivates this provider.
    * This method is automatically invoked by disabling my-location layer. */
    @Override
    public void deactivate() {
        Log.i(TAG,"deactivate");
        // Remove location updates from Location Manager
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);

        onLocationChangedListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i(TAG,"onLocationChanged. Latitude: " + location.getLatitude() + " - Longitude: " + location.getLongitude());
        /* Push location updates to the registered listener..
         * (this ensures that my-location layer will set the blue dot at the new/received location) */
        if (onLocationChangedListener != null) {
            onLocationChangedListener.onLocationChanged(location);
        }

        /* ..and Animate camera to center on that location !
         * (the reason for we created this custom Location Source !) */
        listaRota.add(location);

        if ( listaRota.size() == 1 ) {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude())).title("Inicio"));
        }

        if ( listaRota.size() >= 2 ) {
            drawPolyLineOnMap();
        }

        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()),15));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(TAG,"onStatusChanged: " + s + ", Estado: " + i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        Log.i(TAG,"onProviderEnabled: " + s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        Log.i(TAG,"onProviderDisabled: " + s);
    }
}

public void drawPolyLineOnMap() {

    List<LatLng> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for( Location l : listaRota ) {
        list.add(new LatLng(l.getLatitude(),l.getLongitude()));
    }

    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    polylineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
    polylineOptions.width(15);
    polylineOptions.addAll(list);

    mMap.clear();
    mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That service is [Geofence Monitoring](https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html) and there are a lot of examples and tutorials for using it (e.g. [this one](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-work-with-geofences-on-android--cms-26639)).

Comment: This service supports only 100 areas. This service not works for my application. And, the areas are circular and I need straight limits.

Comment: @Augusto 1) 100 **active** "areas" **per device**; 2)  why it didn't works? 3) anyway you can create circle around the target area, then, when alert is thrown for this circular geofence, evaluate if it is also inside your target area. But it's not the one possible solution: your always can create custom service, as you described.

Comment: My problem is to alert a driver that he has already passed a stretch of road, so circles do not solve my problem. So I'm tracing a polyline and I check with a PolyUtil method and check if the point in question is inside the polyline created with the previous points. Of course, with some tolerance of meters. It was this method that I found most feasible and that I was able to implement. I'm new to this area and your solution I could not implement.